# I've converted a pandas column of objects into datetimes, but after I saved it with to_csv and reload it, the column datatype changed back to objects

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my df:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start_time = ["2020-04-26 17:45:14", "2020-04-17 17:08:54",
              "2020-04-01 17:54:13", "2020-04-07 12:50:19"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ids, "started_at": start_time})
```

First, I've converted the started_at column from strings to datetimes as below:

```
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then, I saved it using to_csv. But when I re-import df, the datatype of "started_at" column changed back to objects. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: If your workflow is entirely in python, then you can use a different filetype like `pickle` which is able to serialize python objects so dtypes and complex objects (like `lists`, `dicts`, ...) will persist across I/O operations: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#:~:text=The%20pandas%20I%2FO%20API%20is%20a%20set%20of,is%20a%20table%20containing%20available%20readers%20and%20writers. `.pkl` files are also way faster to read/write than csv if you do that often.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, csv doesn't store datetime as that is a data type inside Python. When you read the file again, pandas sees non-numeric values and goes "oh this is a string".

The way to go about this is not to try storing something in a CSV file as a pandas datetime, but rather let pandas parse dates at the time of reading the file.

`df = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=["started_at"])`